# Codeblock in android Handler not being executed

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I am uploading video to a localhost webpage.    My code is using a Handler (the syntax of which is working in a different class for signup & login to the app.

However when I run the code in the emulator it creates the handler, run the next line, then skips over the code in the handler.post section.   (I can see handler appears to be deprecated in the documentation but i'm too far down this road to change now).

Any suggestions would be very much appreciated.   (I know there are probably other issues in the code and better ways to do what i'm trying to achieve, I'm just using this as a learning exercise).

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/captureBtn"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Capture Video"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/captureBtn"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="Capture Video"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />



</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import okhttp3.Call;
import okhttp3.Callback;
import okhttp3.MediaType;
import okhttp3.MultipartBody;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.RequestBody;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Storage Permissions
    private static final int REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE = 1;
    private static String[] PERMISSIONS_STORAGE = {
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    };

    Button Upload;
    private final String fileURI = "/storeage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20210424_141744.mp4";
    private static final String serverUri = "http://192.168.0.116/racewatch/upload.php";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Upload = findViewById(R.id.captureBtn);

        Upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Handler handler = new Handler();
                    System.out.println("Hi from here");
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // Start of upload thread
                            //Creating array for parameters
                            String[] field = new String[4];
                            field[0] = "username";
                            field[1] = "userid";
                            field[2] = "lat";
                            field[4] = "lon";

                            //Creating array for data
                            String[] data = new String[4];
                            data[0] = "patsky";
                            data[1] = "21";
                            data[2] = "53.6";
                            data[3] = "-6.1";

                            // instantiate a client - should be a singleton
                            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                                    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                    .build();


                            //   /storeage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/VID_20210424_141744.mp4
                            RequestBody requestBody = new MultipartBody.Builder()
                                    .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
                                    .addFormDataPart(field[0], data[0])
                                    .addFormDataPart(field[1], data[1])
                                    .addFormDataPart(field[2], data[2])
                                    .addFormDataPart(field[3], data[3])
                                    .addFormDataPart("file", "test.mp4", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("video/mp4"), new File(fileURI)))
                                    .build();

                            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                    .url(serverUri)
                                    .post(requestBody)
                                    .build();

                            client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(final Call call, final IOException e) {
                                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error in file upload", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    Log.e("file uuuupload", "exception", e);
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(final Call call, final Response response) throws IOException {

                                    String phpans = response.body().string();//reponse body can be only accessed once
                                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, phpans, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    System.out.println("Error messssage" + phpans);
                                    if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                                        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File uploaded successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        System.out.println("Error messaage" + phpans);
                                    }
                                    // Upload successful
                                }
                            });

                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{
                            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 44);
                }

            }  // end of onClick
        });
    } // end  of onCreate


}
```

AndroidManifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.uploadtoserverexample">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.UploadToServerExample">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: So you've checked whether it reaches the `String[] field = new String[4];` line for example?

Comment: Also `Handler` isn't deprecated, just the constructor you're using.

Comment: It doesn't get to that line, skips straight to else (and passes it as the if condition has already been evaluated and found to be true).    Thanks for the comment on the constructor, I misinterpreted the page on developer.android.com.

Comment: Can you produce a [mre], so I can test it myself?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this.  I've added the code above.  I'm learning thru building each module separately & then adding it to the main project, so what is above is pretty much the set of files.

Comment: I have no issues with your code unfortunately, so there must be something else going on. Are you sure the listener is being fired and the `new Handler()` line is being run?

Comment: Debugging it shows the handler being created and even recognised by the handler.post line, but thanks for taking a look .   I'll keep digging around it.

Comment: That's very odd actually... I'll let you know if I think of something, good luck!